# Discontinuous morphemes in Indo-European languages

Tags: morphology, indo-european

Indo-European is not a language family known for discontinuous morphology, but there are occasional examples. I can think of two:

- The German and Dutch past participle formants, *ge-en* and *ge-t*, e.g. Dutch *ge-nom-en, ge-werk-t*.
- The Ancient Greek present formant *-N-an-*, with infixed nasal before the last consonant of the root (where phonotactically possible), e.g. *lambanō* from the root *lab*.

What other examples of discontinuous morphology in Indo-European languages are there?

Comment: I guess you could consider ablaut roots discontinuous, like "s_ng" as in sing sang sung.

Comment: Arguably the French negative _ne ... pas_ might be analysed as a discontinuous morpheme, but I agree that this would be stretching the definition a bit!

Comment: @ColinFine: You could say *ne...pas* is not that different from *ge...t.* On the other hand, then *either...or* would also count. The difference is that the position of *ge...t* is far more restricted: *ge-`stem`-t*, but *il ne me l'a pas donné*.

Comment: IE is not really my field.  With that caveat, I’d like to suggest proceeding by analogy.  Find languages outside IE that exhibit rich discontinuous morphology, then look for typological parallels with IE languages.  Tagalog is one such non-IE language, and it also happens to be verb-initial.  Is it possible that verb-initial IE languages (like Irish) have innovated instances of DM?

Comment: A quick Google search yields this:  “the tense marker [on an Irish verb] may appear either as a suffix, as an initial mutation of the stem, or as a discontinuous morpheme realized with both initial mutation and a suffix (eg _mhol+f+ainn_ ‘I would praise’).”  (McAuley ed, “The Celtic Languages” p. 67)

Answer (score 3):

There is modern English slang *that is in-fucking-credible*.

Further you could say various forms of reduplication are discontinuous, such as the Greek perfect, where reduplication and perfective suffix must come together or not at all, similar to Dutch/German ge-werk-t. Present stem *lu-*, perfect stem *le-lu-k-*, where *le...k-* together mark the perfect stem. A few verbs also have reduplication in non-perfective stems, but then many Dutch/German words also have *ge-* in non-past-participles, like *ge-voel*. To both *ge...t* and *le...k-* applies that they are perhaps best considered two morphemes each.

Seperable verbs might also count as discontinuous, but they are certainly not single morphemes.

There is a Dutch *h* + reduplicated vowel that are sometimes informally used as an infix for emphasis, mainly in speech:

> KPN dwingen om de post op zondag te bezorgen? Dat kan toch niet, wat zei ik nou net: KPN is een *ondernéhéming*, geen staatsbedrijf.

"Force KPN (postal service) to deliver the post on Sundays? You know that isn't possible, what have I just told you? KPN is an *enterpríhíse,* not a government agency." However, I'm not sure whether this *hV* should be considered a morpheme rather than just a phonetic bit of...something.

Comment: The Greek perfect's a good example; I'd never thought of that as a discontinuous morpheme.

Comment: @TKR: One more thing to consider: Ablaut can change the meaning of a morpheme. Or you could say it is a discontinous change, where it changes something in the middle of a morpheme. The same applies to compensatory lengthening. E.g. Greek *phên-ai* = "to show" (act. aor.), *phan-ai* = "to appear" (pass. aor.).

Comment: Yes, certainly ablaut and other root changes can be seen in that way. What I'm really after (though this wasn't clear from the question) is examples of discontinuous inflectional or derivational morphemes, though.

Answer (score 1):

With Lithuanian reflexive verbs, the particle showing reflexivity goes at the end.  However, if the verb has a prefix like pa-, iš- etc., the reflexive particle comes between this prefix and the stem.  For example:

aiškinti  ‘to explain’

paaiškinti  ‘to explain a little’

aiškintis  ‘to explain oneself’

pasiaiškinti  ‘to explain oneself a little bit;  (reciprocal) to resolve mutual disagreements’

Is there a case for calling –si- an infix?  It seems like a simple question of prefix ordering.  But still, in languages like Latvian or Russian with generally similar verbal morphology, this movement doesn’t take place – the Latvian equivalent of the above series would be ‘skaidrot, paskaidrot, skaidroties, paskaidroties’.   Or looking at it another way, perhaps we could say that Lithuanian is averse to morphological discontinuity, since it stacks the prefixes in front.

Comment: This is an interesting affix-ordering phenomenon, but it isn't really about discontinuous morphology, since the reflexive affix is a different morpheme from the verbal prefixes.

Comment: Another infix is in the imperfective stem of some Russian verbs, but again, this is not really an example of a discontinuous morpheme.

Answer (score 0):

Some Lithuanian verbs show a kind of *vowel grading* between past and present tense combined with tense/person *suffixation*

eg KIRSTI (to cut)

Pres sg 1st, 2nd, 3rd person: kertu kerti kerta

Past sg 1st, 2nd, 3rd person: kirtau kirtai kirto

Since both elements are obligatory for the distinction present vs past you could
argue that they are discontinous morphemes,

eg

Pres sg 1st, 2nd, 3rd person: e_u e_i e_a

Past sg 1st, 2nd, 3rd person: i_au i_ai i_o